# Can't install plugin grails-spring-security-radius

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am writing a project using Grails and Spring Security. I want to use RADIUS for it. As such, I installed the spring-security-core but i can't install spring-security-radius plugins. lugin has a problem?

This error:

> | Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: The following artifacts could not be resolved: net.jradius:jradius-core:jar:1.1.4, net.jradius:jradius-extended:jar:1.1.4, net.jradius:jradius-dictionary:jar:1.1
>   .4: Could not find artifact net.jradius:jradius-core:jar:1.1.4 in grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
>   | Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: The following artifacts could not be resolved: net.jradius:jradius-core:jar:1.1.4, net.jradius:jradius-extended:jar:1.1.4, net.jradius:jradius-dictionary:jar:1.1
>   .4: Could not find artifact net.jradius:jradius-core:jar:1.1.4 in grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
>   | Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: The following artifacts could not be resolved: net.jradius:jradius-core:jar:1.1.4, net.jradius:jradius-extended:jar:1.1.4, net.jradius:jradius-dictionary:jar:1.1
>   .4: Could not find artifact net.jradius:jradius-core:jar:1.1.4 in grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
>   | Error The following artifacts could not be resolved: net.jradius:jradius-core:jar:1.1.4, net.jradius:jradius-extended:jar:1.1.4, net.jradius:jradius-dictionary:jar:1.1.4: Could not find artifact net.jradiu
>   s:jradius-core:jar:1.1.4 in grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins)
>   | Run 'grails dependency-report' for further information.

Answer (score 1):

It hasn't been updated in 3 years, and hasn't endured the silence and loneliness well apparently. I see [at GitHub](https://github.com/smakela/grails-spring-security-radius/) that the author spent some time getting it updated to work with Grails 2.3 and spring-security-core 2.0, so it might be close to working again.

Comment: Check with the author and see how close the update is - you might get lucky.